# In a nested requirement, why use `requires bool_constant<X>::value;` instead of `requires X;`?

Tags: c++, c++20

I was reading [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_random_bit_generator), and found following code in it:

```
template <class G>
concept uniform_random_bit_generator =
  // ...
  requires {
    // ...
    requires std::bool_constant<(G::min() < G::max())>::value;
  };
```

I'm curious why `std::bool_constant` is used here. Isn't it possible to use `requires G::min() < G::max();` directly, like so:

```
template <class G>
concept uniform_random_bit_generator =
  // ...
  requires {
    // ...
    requires G::min() < G::max();
  };
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `requires G::min() < G::max();` is a hard error if `G::min() < G::max()` doesn't form a constant expression, but `requires std::bool_constant<(G::min() < G::max())>::value` would just be `false`.

Take for example this type and these concepts:

```cpp
struct foo {
    static int min();
    static int max();
};

template<typename T>
concept min_max_1 = requires {
    requires T::min() < T::max();
};

template<typename T>
concept min_max_2 = requires {
    requires std::bool_constant<(T::min() < T::max())>::value;
};

// Which are entirely equivalent to
template<typename T>
concept min_max_1 = T::min() < T::max();

template<typename T>
concept min_max_2 = std::bool_constant<(T::min() < T::max())>::value;
```

`static_assert(!min_max_2<foo>);` succeeds as expected, because it forms an invalid expression so it is false.

`static_assert(!min_max_1<foo>);` creates a compile time error, because `T::min() < T::max()` is a valid expression, it's just not a bool constant expression, which is what is expected.