# Type-constraining template parameters inside concept

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Is there a way to write a concept that can produce a clear and detailed error message when one of the template parameters of the type being checked doesn't satisfy a specific type-constraint?

For example, when I have a concept which checks for availability of a certain member-function:

```
template<typename T>
concept has_func = requires(T t)
{ t.func(); };
```

I could write a concept that uses some type-trait to check if each of the template parameters of the type being checked fulfills the `has_func` type-constraint:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename>
struct all_func_elems : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> typename Tp, has_func... Ts>
struct all_func_elems<Tp<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
concept has_func_elems = all_func_elems<T>::value;
```

So that, when using the following types:

```
struct bad {};
struct good {
    void func();
};
template<typename...>
struct tuple {};

using ok = tuple<good, good, good>;
using nope = tuple<good, bad, good>;
```

We get the expected results when testing the concept `has_func_elems`:

```
static_assert(has_func_elems<ok>);
static_assert(not has_func_elems<nope>);
```

The problem with this is, is that when testing a type that doesn't satisfy the `has_func_elems` concept:

```
static_assert(has_func_elems<nope>);
```

The error message produced is not clear nor detailed at all. There is no telling which template parameter didn't satisfy the `has_func` concept.

```
<source>:39:1: error: static assertion failed
static_assert(has_func_elems<nope>);
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:39:15: note: because 'nope' (aka 'tuple<good, bad, good>')
    does not satisfy 'has_func_elems'
static_assert(has_func_elems<nope>);
              ^
<source>:14:27: note: because 'all_func_elems<tuple<good, bad, good> >::value'
evaluated to false
concept has_func_elems = all_func_elems<T>::value;
                         ^
```

Another way of writing the `has_func_elems` concept could be by using a templated lambda instead, to unpack the type being checked and apply the `has_func` type-constraint to each template parameter:

```
template<typename T>
concept has_func_elems = requires(T t) {
    []<template<typename...> typename Tp, has_func... Ts>(Tp<Ts...>){}(t);
};
```

But this still runs into the same problem, of not providing a clear and detailed error message when checking a type that doesn't satisfy the `has_func_elems` concept:

```
<source>:45:1: error: static assertion failed
static_assert(has_func_elems<nope>);
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:45:15: note: because 'nope' (aka 'tuple<good, bad, good>')
    does not satisfy 'has_func_elems'
static_assert(has_func_elems<nope>);
              ^
<source>:18:5: note: because
'[]<template <typename ...> class Tp, has_func ...Ts>(Tp<Ts...>) {}(t)'
would be invalid: no matching function for call to object of type
'(lambda at <source>:18:5)'
    []<template<typename...> typename Tp, has_func... Ts>(Tp<Ts...>){}(t);
    ^
```

One way to go about this, is to apply the `has_func` type-constraint on each of the template parameters with the use of another lambda:

```
template<typename T>
concept has_func_elems = requires(T t) {
    []<template<typename...> typename Tp, typename... Ts>(Tp<Ts...>)
    { [](has_func auto...){}(Ts{}...); }(t);
};
```

This does produce a clear and detailed error message that specifies which template parameter is the culprit and why it doesn't satisfy the `has_func` type-constraint:

```
<source>:24:7: error: no matching function for call to object of type
'(lambda at <source>:24:7)'
    { [](has_func auto...){}(Ts{}...); }(t);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:23:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
'(anonymous class)::operator()<tuple, good, bad, good>' requested here
    []<template<typename...> typename Tp, typename... Ts>(Tp<Ts...>)
    ^
<source>:23:5: note: in instantiation of requirement here
    []<template<typename...> typename Tp, typename... Ts>(Tp<Ts...>)
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:22:27: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint
    expression here
concept has_func_elems = requires(T t) {
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:49:19: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept
    'has_func_elems<tuple<good, bad, good>>' requested here
static_assert(not has_func_elems<nope>);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:24:7: note: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied
[with auto:1 = <good, bad, good>]
    { [](has_func auto...){}(Ts{}...); }(t);
      ^
<source>:24:10: note: because 'bad' does not satisfy 'has_func'
    { [](has_func auto...){}(Ts{}...); }(t);
         ^
<source>:5:5: note: because 't.func()' would be invalid: no member named
    'func' in 'bad'
{ t.func(); };
    ^
```

However, the problem with this solution is that it produces a hard-error, which causes the assertion of `static_assert(not has_func_elems<nope>);` to fail compilation. It's probably due to a substitution failure outside of the immediate context, but it's not entirely clear to me how this works within requires-expressions.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/vdqz8qzWK)

Comment: That seems impossible but maybe someone might come up with something. That last suggestion seems creative but the fact that you use `Ts{}...` is prone to error because not all types are necessarily initializable as such. A second requires clause would fix that, but when I attempted it gcc seems to optimize the expression (?) and that just produces `expression evaluated to false` error.

Comment: @guard3 I liked this version of the example because it was rather short and elegant, in any case, please consider the constructability of `Ts` to be irrelevant to this question. But feel free to change it to: `[]<has_func...>{}.template operator()<Ts...>();` if it bothers you. There are also other straightforward ways to go around this, e.g.: `template<has_func...> struct check_func {};` and then just return an instance of it within the lambda of the requires-expression: `return check_func<Ts...>{};`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

The OP, as noted in the comments, concisely identified the two key elements of this approach as 1) using SFINAE to extract the types that do not conform to the concept and 2) wrapping the concept in a functor so that it can be passed around as a template parameter. Here is OP's streamlined design based on these ideas (you can also find the code at [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/en5osE3eP) or [GitHub](https://github.com/cpp-core/so.git)):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
concept has_func = requires(T t)
{ t.func(); };

///////////////////////////// final concept ///////////////////////////////////
template<typename T>
struct check_func
{ using type = T; };

template<template<typename...> typename Tp, typename T>
struct check_func<Tp<T>> : check_func<T> {};

template<template<typename...> typename Tp, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct check_func<Tp<T, Ts...>> : check_func<T> {};

template<template<typename...> typename Tp, has_func T, typename... Ts>
struct check_func<Tp<T, Ts...>> : check_func<Tp<Ts...>> {};

template<typename T>
using check_func_t = typename check_func<T>::type;

template<typename T>
concept has_func_elems = has_func<check_func_t<T>>;

///////////////////////////// testing types ///////////////////////////////////
struct good { void func(); };
struct bad {};

template<typename...>
struct tuple {};

using ok = tuple<good, good, good>;
using nope = tuple<good, bad, good>;
///////////////////////////// unit tests //////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    static_assert(has_func_elems<ok>);
    static_assert(not has_func_elems<nope>);
    static_assert(has_func_elems<nope>); // good error message:
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ make static_assert_v4
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/static_assert_v4.dir/src/static_assert_v4.cpp.o
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v4.\
cpp:45:5: error:
      static assertion failed
    static_assert(has_func_elems<nope>); // good error message:
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v4.\
cpp:45:19: note:
      because 'nope' (aka 'tuple<good, bad, good>') does not satisfy 'has_func_elems'
    static_assert(has_func_elems<nope>); // good error message:
                  ^
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v4.\
cpp:29:26: note:
      because 'check_func_t<tuple<good, bad, good>>' (aka 'bad') does not satisfy 'has_func'
concept has_func_elems = has_func<check_func_t<T>>;
                         ^
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v4.\
cpp:9:5: note:
      because 't.func()' would be invalid: no member named 'func' in 'bad'
{ t.func(); };
    ^
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/static_assert_v4.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/static_assert_v4.dir/src/\
static_assert_v4.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:194: CMakeFiles/static_assert_v4.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:201: CMakeFiles/static_assert_v4.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:176: static_assert_v4] Error 2
```

**End Update**

The following approach leverages standard template meta-programming to isolate the subtypes that do not conform to the desired concept into a typelist. The meta-functions `push_front_typelist_t` and `filter_typelist_t` can be re-used across different concepts to accomplish this task.

Once the non-conforming subtypes are represented by a typelist, the concept `HasFuncN` can use that type to encourage the compiler to generate a useful error message.

This method addresses some of the shortcomings of my first two answers.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<class T, class U>
struct push_front_typelist {
    template<class Tx, class Lx>
    struct impl;

    template<class Tx, template<class...> class Lx, class... Us>
    struct impl<Tx, Lx<Us...>> { using type = Lx<Tx, Us...>; };

    using type = typename impl<T, U>::type;
};

template<class T, class U>
using push_front_typelist_t = typename push_front_typelist<T, U>::type;

template<class T, class F>
struct filter_typelist {
    template<class Lx>
    struct impl;

    template<template<class...> class Lx>
    struct impl<Lx<>> { using type = Lx<>; };

    template<template<class...> class Lx, class U, class... Us>
    struct impl<Lx<U, Us...>> {
        using remainder = typename filter_typelist<Lx<Us...>, F>::type;
        using prepended = push_front_typelist_t<U, remainder>;
        using type = std::conditional_t<F{}.template operator()<U>(), remainder, prepended>;
    };

    using type = typename impl<T>::type;
};

template<class T, class F>
using filter_typelist_t = typename filter_typelist<T, F>::type;

template<class T>
concept HasFunc = requires (T a) { a.func(); };

struct has_func {
    template<class T>
    consteval bool operator()() const { return HasFunc<T>; }
};

template<class T, class U = filter_typelist_t<T, has_func>>
concept HasFuncN = (std::tuple_size_v<U> == 0) or HasFunc<std::tuple_element_t<0, U>>;

struct good { void func(); };
struct bad { };

using ok = std::tuple<good, good, good>;
using nope = std::tuple<good, bad, good>;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    static_assert(HasFuncN<ok>);
    static_assert(HasFuncN<nope>);
    static_assert(not HasFuncN<ok>);
    static_assert(not HasFuncN<nope>);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ make static_assert_v3 && static_assert_v3
 CMakeFiles/static_assert_v3.dir/src/static_assert_v3.cpp.o
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v3.\
cpp:61:5: error:
      static assertion failed
    static_assert(HasFuncN<nope>);
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v3.\
cpp:61:19: note:
      because 'nope' (aka 'tuple<good, bad, good>') does not satisfy 'HasFuncN'
    static_assert(HasFuncN<nope>);
                  ^
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v3.\
cpp:51:21: note:
      because 'std::tuple_size_v<std::tuple<bad> > == 0' (1 == 0) evaluated to false
concept HasFuncN = (std::tuple_size_v<U> == 0) or HasFunc<std::tuple_element_t<0, U>>;
                    ^
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v3.\
cpp:51:51: note:
      and 'std::tuple_element_t<0, tuple<bad>>' (aka '__type_pack_element<0UL, bad>') does not
      satisfy 'HasFunc'
concept HasFuncN = (std::tuple_size_v<U> == 0) or HasFunc<std::tuple_element_t<0, U>>;
                                                  ^
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v3.\
cpp:43:38: note:
      because 'a.func()' would be invalid: no member named 'func' in 'bad'
concept HasFunc = requires (T a) { a.func(); };
                                     ^
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v3.\
cpp:62:5: error:
      static assertion failed due to requirement '!HasFuncN<std::tuple<good, good, good>>'
    static_assert(not HasFuncN<ok>);
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/static_assert_v3.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/static_assert_v3.dir/src/\
static_assert_v3.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:166: CMakeFiles/static_assert_v3.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:173: CMakeFiles/static_assert_v3.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: static_assert_v3] Error 2
```

Comment: Really awesome idea of using SFINAE techniques to extract the type that doesn't satisfy the concept and have that checked a final time. Also, pretty cool idea of wrapping a concept into a functor to be able to pass it around as a template parameter, I don't think I've seen that before. I was able to shorten your SFINEA trick a little bit at the cost of making it less generic, but I do think it fits in here nicely: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/en5osE3eP). It also returns false when the tuple is empty, which I think makes a bit more sense. If you include it to your answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: Thanks for streamlining the design, I feel we reached a good, creative solution.

Comment: Just to clarify on this, the adaptation that I had posted of your solution does not wrap the concept `has_func` in a functor or lambda. I just pointed it out because it happened to have caught my attention when I was reading your solution. It could easily be modified to do so, however.

Answer (score 1):

While the following solution is imperfect, it is simple, robust, fails with a static assertion and has good error messages. It relies on the fact that a constraint disjunction has short circuiting. The shortcoming is that it is limited to a finite length tuple. Even so, I think it could be useful.

Maybe someone can refine it further. I am using clang-15 with std=c++20. The code with build instructions can also be found in the GitHub repo [cpp-core/so](https://github.com/cpp-core/so.git).

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<class T>
concept HasFunc = requires (T a) { a.func(); };

template<size_t I, class T>
concept HasFuncI = std::tuple_size_v<T> <= I or HasFunc<std::tuple_element_t<I, T>>;

template<class T>
concept HasFuncs = HasFuncI<0, T> and HasFuncI<1, T> and HasFuncI<2, T> and HasFuncI<3, T> and
    HasFuncI<4, T> and HasFuncI<5, T> and HasFuncI<6, T> and HasFuncI<7, T> and
    std::tuple_size_v<T> < 8;

struct good { void func(); };
struct bad { };

using ok = std::tuple<good, good, good>;
using nope = std::tuple<good, bad, good>;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    static_assert(HasFuncs<ok>);
    static_assert(HasFuncs<nope>);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling produces a static assertion with the following error message:

```
$ make static_assert
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/static_assert.dir/src/static_assert.cpp.o
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert.cpp\
:26:5: error:
      static assertion failed
    static_assert(HasFuncs<nope>);
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert.cpp\
:26:19: note:
      because 'nope' (aka 'tuple<good, bad, good>') does not satisfy 'HasFuncs'
    static_assert(HasFuncs<nope>);
                  ^
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert.cpp\
:14:39: note:
      because 'HasFuncI<1, std::tuple<good, bad, good> >' evaluated to false
concept HasFuncs = HasFuncI<0, T> and HasFuncI<1, T> and HasFuncI<2, T> and HasFuncI<3, T> and
                                      ^
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert.cpp\
:11:20: note:
      because 'std::tuple_size_v<std::tuple<good, bad, good> > <= 1UL' (3 <= 1) evaluated to
      false
concept HasFuncI = std::tuple_size_v<T> <= I or HasFunc<std::tuple_element_t<I, T>>;
                   ^
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert.cpp\
:11:49: note:
      and 'std::tuple_element_t<1UL, tuple<good, bad, good>>' (aka '__type_pack_element<1UL,
      good, bad, good>') does not satisfy 'HasFunc'
concept HasFuncI = std::tuple_size_v<T> <= I or HasFunc<std::tuple_element_t<I, T>>;
                                                ^
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert.cpp\
:8:38: note:
      because 'a.func()' would be invalid: no member named 'func' in 'bad'
concept HasFunc = requires (T a) { a.func(); };
                                     ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: It's an interesting idea and I appreciate your effort, but it's not the solution I'm looking for. Having to manually extract the template parameters of the type to check to a predefined fixed amount, is not an acceptable limitation.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. Since concepts can't be specialized, I cannot figure out any way to recurse or iterate like you typically would with meta-programming.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution, while imperfect like my first answer attempt, is simple, robust, has detailed error messages and fails with a static assertion. It relies on the ability of concepts to use the result of `constexpr` functions. It overcomes the predefined, fixed arity limitation of my first answer attempt, which did not satisfy the question requirements. As result, it is also less verbose.

One drawback is that it fails with two static assertions instead of one. One assertion is at the detailed level of the individual type while the other is at the composite type level. Maybe someone can refine the technique further. Again, I am using clang-15 with std=c++20. The code with build instructions can also be found in the GitHub repo [cpp-core/so](https://github.com/cpp-core/so.git).

```cpp
template<class T>
concept HasFunc = requires (T a) { a.func(); };

template<class T, size_t... Is>
consteval bool hash_func_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    static_assert((HasFunc<std::tuple_element_t<Is, T>> && ...));
    return (HasFunc<std::tuple_element_t<Is, T>> && ...);
}

template<class T, size_t... Is>
consteval bool not_hash_func_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    static_assert((not HasFunc<std::tuple_element_t<Is, T>> || ...));
    return (not HasFunc<std::tuple_element_t<Is, T>> || ...);
}

template<class T, size_t N = std::tuple_size_v<T>>
concept HasFuncsN = hash_func_impl<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});

template<class T, size_t N = std::tuple_size_v<T>>
concept NotHasFuncsN = not_hash_func_impl<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});

struct good { void func(); };
struct bad { };

using ok = std::tuple<good, good, good>;
using nope = std::tuple<good, bad, good>;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    static_assert(HasFuncsN<ok>);
    static_assert(NotHasFuncsN<nope>);
    static_assert(HasFuncsN<nope>);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ make static_assert_v2 && static_assert_v2
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/static_assert_v2.dir/src/static_assert_v2.cpp.o
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v2.\
cpp:12:5: error:
      static assertion failed
    static_assert((HasFunc<std::tuple_element_t<Is, T>> && ...));
    ^              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v2.\
cpp:17:21: note:
      in instantiation of function template specialization 'hash_func_impl<std::tuple<good, bad,
      good>, 0UL, 1UL, 2UL>' requested here
concept HasFuncsN = hash_func_impl<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
                    ^
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v2.\
cpp:17:21: note:
      while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
concept HasFuncsN = hash_func_impl<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v2.\
cpp:27:19: note:
      while checking the satisfaction of concept 'HasFuncsN<std::tuple<good, bad, good>, 3UL>'
      requested here
    static_assert(HasFuncsN<nope>);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v2.\
cpp:12:20: note:
      because 'std::tuple_element_t<1UL, tuple<good, bad, good>>' (aka '__type_pack_element<1UL,
      good, bad, good>') does not satisfy 'HasFunc'
    static_assert((HasFunc<std::tuple_element_t<Is, T>> && ...));
                   ^
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v2.\
cpp:8:38: note:
      because 'a.func()' would be invalid: no member named 'func' in 'bad'
concept HasFunc = requires (T a) { a.func(); };
                                     ^
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v2.\
cpp:27:5: error:
      static assertion failed
    static_assert(HasFuncsN<nope>);
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v2.\
cpp:27:19: note:
      because 'nope' (aka 'tuple<good, bad, good>') does not satisfy 'HasFuncsN'
    static_assert(HasFuncsN<nope>);
                  ^
/Users/mmelton/work/so/type-constraining-template-parameters-inside-concept/src/static_assert_v2.\
cpp:17:21: note:
      because 'hash_func_impl<std::tuple<good, bad, good> >(std::make_index_sequence<3UL>{})'
      evaluated to false
concept HasFuncsN = hash_func_impl<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
                    ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is not really helpful because it will obviously create a hard-error when evaluating `static_assert(not HasFuncsN<nope>);`, which is specifically what I'm trying to prevent. Also, it's probably just a coincidence but for some reason your answer reads very much like a ChatGPT generated answer.

Comment: If anything, ChatGPT is imitating me because some of my internet tracks must surely be in its training data. :). For the record, my posts to date are all my original, human generated content. I guess my natural writing style is just robotic enough to pass as an AI -- a reverse Turning tests of sorts.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the negative case that you brought up. This is definitely not quite as clean and adds some boiler plate. Besides that, does it address the issue? I feel like I may not fully understand the nuance of the requirements.

Comment: It was not my intention to question your authenticity, it was just the way you phrased the first paragraph that felt very robotic or something :P. Anyway, my concern is that checking the concept itself should not result in a compilation error when passing in some type that doesn't adhere to its constraints. In that case, it should just evaluate to false, this allows for the concept to be used in a SFINAE-friendly context. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63547982/in-a-nested-requirement-why-use-requires-bool-constantxvalue-instead-of) answer for some more info about that.